# How to align iconbuttons in card widget flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble issues aligning my icon buttons to the middle of the card. As you can see in the picture, the icon buttons are on top attached to the top of the card.

How do I make it meet at the half size of the card? Any suggestions? (I want the buttons to be located at the middle of the card)

Tried: I tried putting padding or wrap my Row widget with a center, but it doesn't work.

```
 child: new Container(
            height: 150.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 8.0,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(Icons.sticky_note_2),
                            iconSize: 35,
                            color: Colors.lightBlue),
                        Text(
                          "Notes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => QuizRoute()),
                            );
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.quiz),
                          iconSize: 35,
                        ),
                          Text(
                          "Quizzes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => EbooksRoute()),
                            );
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.auto_stories),
                          iconSize: 35,
                        ),
                          Text(
                          "Ebooks",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: Try wrapping the `Row` widget with a `Center` widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code and set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` to every `Column` widget.  Refer [`layout`](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout) and [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)

```
Container(
  height: 150.0,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    elevation: 8.0,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.sticky_note_2),
                iconSize: 35,
                color: Colors.lightBlue),
            Text(
              "Notes",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.quiz),
              iconSize: 35,
            ),
            Text(
              "Quizzes",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.auto_stories),
              iconSize: 35,
            ),
            Text(
              "Ebooks",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 2):

##### What is the issue?

You are using center alignment in the `row` but not inside the `column`. Now `column` is taking the height of entire row but the children of the `column` is not aligned `center`.

##### Solution:

Try adding `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` in each of your column

##### Present Code:

```
Row
mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center
|_Column
|_Column
|_Column
```

##### Required Code:

```
Row
mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center
|_Column
  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center  Add these to every column
|_Column
  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center
|_Column
  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center
```

For the complete code refer : [@Ravindra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75133288/13431819)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your "Row" widget with the following code, this will solve your issue.

**Solution** : Give your Column center alignment

mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center

```
      child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.sticky_note_2),
                      iconSize: 35,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue),
                  const Text(
                    "Notes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Navigator.push(
                      //   context,
                      //   MaterialPageRoute(
                      //       builder: (context) => QuizRoute()),
                      // );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.quiz),
                    iconSize: 35,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Quizzes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Navigator.push(
                      //   context,
                      //   MaterialPageRoute(
                      //       builder: (context) => EbooksRoute()),
                      // );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.auto_stories),
                    iconSize: 35,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Ebooks",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
```